# Show citations in text when clicking on element in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, citing

so my wish would be to be shown all the times I cited an element in the bibliography in the text. So the vice versa operation of clicking onto a particular citation and being directed to the bibliography (this works in my code already). I'd like to click on an element in the latter however and then be directed to all the places where I cited this source in my text. I am using biblatex in texmaker with miktex. Is this somehow possible? Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: The feature you seem to be looking for is called backref.

Comment: Definitely helps a lot!! It's not quite what I want but good enough I guess.
Remark: Using biblatex I had to write the line backref=true into the preamble of the biblatex package, not the hyperref package.

Comment: Thank you both!!